# How to change the language of a result of ":results output code" in emacs org-mode

Tags: emacs, org-mode, org-babel

I have a org file which contains a block like this:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC sh :exports results :results output code
sed -n '9,36 p' ./code/convert.c
#+END_SRC
```

`C-c C-c` on the `BEGIN_SRC` will give me the following result:

```
#+RESULTS:
#+begin_src sh
 // here is some C code
#+end_src
```

How to change the language of a result of ":results output code" so that I can get an output like this:

```
#+RESULTS:
#+begin_src C
 // here is some C code
#+end_src
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
#+BEGIN_SRC sh :exports results :results output code :wrap SRC C
sed -n '9,36 p' ./code/convert.c
#+END_SRC
```

the `SRC` of `#+BEGIN_SRC` and `#+END_SRC` be replaced by `:wrap XXX` will `#+BEGIN_XXX` and `#+END_XXX`

Comment: In my case, I found only the flags `:results output :wrap src C` to be necessary.

Comment: I also need to export that segment as html